# simplexml_load_string - parse error due to unicode characters in payload

Tags: php, unicode, simplexml

I have a problem with `simplexml_load_string` erring with parse errors due to an xml payload coming from a database with unicode characters in it.

I'm at a loss how to get php to read this and use the xml like I normally would. The code has been working fine until people were getting creative with data being submitted.

Unfortunately I cannot modify the source data, I have to work with what I receive, to give you an idea, one field that's breaking it in the original raw receipt looks like :

```
<FirstName></FirstName>
```

Previously the code works fine by parsing the xml with a simple line of :

```
$xmlresult = simplexml_load_string($result, 'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

However with these unicode characters, it just errors. 
Depending on what I use to view the data if I dump the raw payload it can look like:

```
 <d83d><dc3a>
```

or `<U+D83D><U+DC3A>`

Reading a bit on stack, it seemed DOM might work but didn't have any luck there either.

The incoming payload does have the header:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

data comes in via

```
<data type="cdata"><![CDATA[<payload>
```

I'm at a complete loss, hopefully can get some help here to get me over this hump with this data handling.

Comment: ` <d83d><dc3a>`? Assuming those are codepoints, that's a UTF-16 surrogate pair that should never show up in UTF-8. (Both codepoints are invalid Unicode ones that are only allowed in that one specific encoding to encode characters outside the BMP.) I bet that somewhere along the line, UTF-16 text was treated as UCS-2 and then that was converted to UTF-8, and none of those steps actually validated their data.

Comment: I can't confirm but I believe how such data arrived was due to validation being turned off on name and address fields due to characters received in a couple of countries, which led to this problem. However I have no control over that and need to find a way to work with it and stop this script from erroring in full due to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been staring at this for days and it seems one thing I didn't try was to wrap my curl call function with utf8_encode like this :

```
    $result = utf8_encode(do_curl($xmlbuildquery));
```

My do_curl function is just a separate function to call the curl procedure, nothing more.
Doing that, I'm able to parse the results, instead of those unicode characters showing up, instead its displaying as

```
[firstname] => í ½í°º
```

(the above is result of print_r($result); after
    $xmldata = simplexml_load_string((string)$xmlresult->body->function->data);

With that in place the xml is now parsing finally. Oddly this sparked my curiosity further as this information is provided via csv thats imported into a mysql database and when I look up the same record its shown as :

```
 FirstName: ????
```

with the table type set too :
   `FirstName` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

That might suggest their not utf8_encoding the output to the csv perhaps, separate from this issue but just interesting.

And finally, my script is able to run again!!